# What wildflower could this be?

Tags: wildflowers

[image]
I planted mixed wildflower seeds and thisvis what came up. The stems are about18" tall right now and are stiff and fuzzy. The leaves are wide and green. There are no blooms yet.

Comment: This is the only plant type that grew from the mix? Do you still have the pack or a list of seeds in the mix? Did the mix per chance contain sunflower seeds?

Comment: @Stephie Per chance?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger ^_^

Comment: Whatever is growing needs help; moisture a bit of compost, get rid of grasses, at least thin, a bit of fertilizer and thin that tree for more sun.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got sunflowers!

[image: sunflower, Helianthemum]

Comment: There are about a zillion different kinds of these. Some produce one big flower at 14 feet, others are bushier with lots of smaller blooms.

Comment: Do you see where I've given a species or variety?  Not happening from a photo.  It is a sunflower, the highest on the evolutionary scale for dicots.  From there they could find their seed packet for details. Not fair to expect ID from photos!!  Grins.  Bamboo can do it best, I am...learning how to not have plant material in my hands, knowing the zone...we'll get other opinions and we all are able to learn how to ID from photos.

Comment: Not complaining, just pointing out. I live where the plants are native, and they cross-pollinate like crazy. The second generation is always different, and liable to take over your lawn if you don't mow regularly.

Comment: Lawns have to be mowed once per week otherwise they are called a pasture, not a lawn.  The second generation is always different...somewhat.  That is how this works.  Pollination for exacting seeds has to be done in sterile rooms with positive pressure.  If you want to call your lawn a lawn, it is an entirely different mentality.  You either accept or don't grow a lawn.  Lawns do not have to be the sucky monster people have made of them.  I never used pesticides in my commercial landscapes.  Throwing wildflower seed on a bald area of grass...makes an artificial garden.  Our responsibility...

Answer (score 0):

Daisy or purple coneflower ,could be dwarf sunflower but is that a wild flower.